# Soft keyboard automatic capitalization with LibGDX

Tags: android, libgdx, android-softkeyboard

I'm writing an app for Android using LibGDX. When the user enters a text field the soft keyboard shows up, but the shift key is not pressed; moreover, after the user inserts a period, the shift key doesn't toggle automatically. Does anybody know how to turn on the automatic capitalization?

Thanks

**Additional info**

The LibGDX backend for Android opens the keyboard using the following code:

```
InputMethodManager manager = (InputMethodManager)context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
View view = ((AndroidGraphics)app.getGraphics()).getView();
view.setFocusable(true);
view.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
manager.showSoftInput(((AndroidGraphics)app.getGraphics()).getView(), 0);
```

I don't need to do everything through the frontend, I'm able to add custom code into the Android backend.